# Does selecting data from heap (table without clustered index) with nolock block writers?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I tried replicating the scenario given here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-curious-case-of-the-bulk_operation-lock-during-a-heap-nolock-scan/

Created 2 tables - table1 with clustered index, table2 without any index.

When I write a select query `with (lock)` on table1, there is Sch-S lock applied. Similarly, when I write the same query on table2, there also it is a Sch-S lock.

Neither case applied the S lock like shown in the above link.

To check locks I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
  WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID()
  AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.table1');
```

Does selecting data from heap (table without clustered index) with nolock block writers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does selecting data from heap (table without clustered index) with nolock block writers?

Only writers performing a **bulk load***, as explained by Paul Randal in the link provided:

> The BULK_OPERATION lock prevents a bulk load from happening while a NOLOCK scan (or versioned scan) is happening. It’s acquired in S mode so there can be multiple concurrent scans occurring. A bulk load will acquire the lock in IX mode, preventing any NOLOCK or versioned scans from starting until the bulk load has finished.

* **bulk load** here refers to the special mechanism that allows multiple concurrent bulk load to heap tables without indexes when using `bcp`, `BULK INSERT`, or SSIS. In these cases a `BU` table lock is taken instead of an exclusive lock. See the [Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)) for more details.

The special `BULK_OPERATION` lock does not conflict with 'ordinary' table, page, or row locks taken by 'ordinary' inserts/updates/deletes.

Bulk loading clustered tables is possible but uses a different mechanism where the `BULK_OPERATION` lock is not required.

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me.  It helps if you flush the page cache before the table scan to slow it down. eg

```
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
go
select avg(somecol) ap
from someheap with (nolock)
```

And check the query plan to make sure you're getting an unordered table scan.

Another trick for observing quick things is to introduce a time-wasting scalar-valued function like:

```
create or alter function dbo.delay(@ms int)
returns int as
begin
   declare @start datetime2 = sysdatetime()
   while datediff(ms,@start,sysdatetime()) < @ms
   begin
     declare @h bigint = checksum(0x29374190273401923470912384709123)
   end
   return @ms
end
```

So you can make a scan as slow as you want, so long as you have a streaming plan.

In AdventureWorksDW, I created a large heap like this

```
select top 25000000 s.* 
into someheap 
from FactInternetSales s,  FactInternetSales s2
```

then ran

```
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
go
select avg(UnitPrice) ap
from someheap with (nolock)
```

which took long enough to switch over and run

```
SELECT
    [resource_type],
    [resource_subtype],
    [resource_associated_entity_id],
    [request_mode]
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE
    [resource_type] != N'DATABASE';
```

and see the BULK_OPERATION lock

[image]

Comment: Does this lock block writes?

Comment: See Paul's answer.  It does not block writers, but a NOLOCK query may return wrong results or fail if there are concurrent writers.